# How can an android app add an IPv6 address to an interface?

Tags: android, ipv6

I would like to add an IPv6 address to my wifi interface from within an android app.  I don't want to replace the existing addresses, just add one.

I can not find anything on the ConnectionManager interface for this.

I've tried using `adb shell` to invoke `ip -6 addr add 2001:stuff/64 dev wlan0`, but I get

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I assume I would get similar results if I invoke it from within an android app, but I haven't tested that assumption.

I would really like to accomplish this without rooting the device.

Comment: Adding an address without root from an app? Sorry, no way.